# Как корректно использование дженерики в данном примере?

Tags: java, generics, рефлексия, аннотации, okhttp

Есть задача А, B и С. И по сути дела возможно я не корректным методом решаю задачи A и B, но задача C следующая.
Есть интерфейс содержащий методы и аннотации:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("/api/v1/smart/status")
    Call<SessionStatusResponse> postWorkChangeStatus(@Body WorkChangeStatusRequestData sessionStatusData);

    @POST("/api/v1/smart/sensor")
    Call<SensorDataResponse> postWorkSensorData(@Body SensorRequestData sensorData);

    @GET("/api/v1/smart/sensor")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AuthConfirmPhoneResponse> getWorkSensorData(@Field("number") String id);
}
```

Я хочу получить `Map<String, List<String>>` в которой в качестве ключа будет выступать путь (значение аннотации, например "/api/v1/smart/sensor") и в качестве значения имя аннотации (если вы знакомы с okhttp то вы их встречали). То есть должны получить в данном случае `{"/api/v1/smart/sensor":["POST", "GET"], ...}`

Получаю эти данные с помощью рефлексии следующим способом:

```
    void parse() {
       methods = clazz.getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(POST.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(POST.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
                else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(GET.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(GET.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
                else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(DELETE.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(DELETE.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
                else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(PUT.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(PUT.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
                else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(HEAD.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(HEAD.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
                else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(OPTIONS.class))
                    annotationValues.put(methods[i].getAnnotation(OPTIONS.class).value(), new ArrayList<String>());
            }
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(POST.class)) {
//                parse(methods[i], POST.class);
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(POST.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(POST.class.getSimpleName());
            } else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(GET.class)) {
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(GET.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(GET.class.getSimpleName());
            } else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(DELETE.class)) {
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(DELETE.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(DELETE.class.getSimpleName());
            } else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(PUT.class)) {
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(PUT.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(PUT.class.getSimpleName());
            } else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(HEAD.class)) {
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(HEAD.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(HEAD.class.getSimpleName());
            } else if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(OPTIONS.class)) {
                String path = methods[i].getAnnotation(OPTIONS.class).value();
                annotationValues.get(path).add(OPTIONS.class.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Выглядит не очень красиво. Решил написать следующий метод, который принимает метод и класс подозреваемой аннотации:

```
private <T extends Annotation> void parse(Method method, Class<T> postClass) {
        String test = ((T)method.getAnnotation(postClass)).value(); //ошибка!
        Log.d(logTag, "========TESTVALUE: " + test);
    }
```

Но возникает ошибка компиляции, которая вполне оправдана, так как заранее не известно, будет ли у класса Т, наследника Annotation метод value().
У аннотаций okhttp общего предка не нашел.

Возможно ли каким либо образом написать подобный метод или решить данную задачу элегантнее?

Comment: Можно получить значение `value`  по рефлекшену.

Answer (score 2):

Первое что бросается в глаза это `methods[i].isAnnotationPresent`. Самое оптимальное из метода получать array задекларированных аннотаций `method.getDeclaredAnnotations()`. А так как array содержит объекты, то мы можем получить их SimpleName: `annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName()` и далее благополучно заворачиваем в `switch`

Второе - дублированный код наполнения мапки. На мой взгляд это проще вынести в отдельный метод со всеми сопутствующими проверками.

Третье - использовать паттерн dependency injection. `parse` принимает на вход любое количество объектов и далее они анализируются. Так же можно сделать еще один метод который будет принимать на вход array методов и валидировать/фильтровать их. Грубо говоря разделить код на логические части (методы) и передавать уже в них объекты.

Результат выполнения ниже приведенного кода `Result: {/api/v1/smart/status=[GET, POST]}`

```
public class Main {

    private static Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] asd) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        parse(new Main(), new Integer("1"));
        System.out.println("Result: " + map);
    }

    private static void parse(Object... objects) {
        for (Object o : objects) {
            for (Method method : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                    switch (annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName()) {
                        case "POST":
                            addToMap(((POST) annotation).value(), "POST");
                            break;
                        case "GET":
                            addToMap(((GET) annotation).value(), "GET");
                            break;
                        case "DELETE":
                        case "PUT":
                        case "HEAD":
                        case "OPTIONS":
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addToMap(String path, String httpMethod) {
        if (path != null) {
            List<String> list = map.get(path);
            if (list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            list.add(httpMethod);
            map.put(path, list);
        }
    }

    @GET("/api/v1/smart/status")
    private void fooMeethod() {}

    @POST(value = "/api/v1/smart/status")
    private void barMeethod() {}

    @Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({METHOD})
    private @interface GET { String value(); }

    @Retention(RUNTIME) @Target({METHOD})
    private @interface POST { String value(); }
}
```

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ, Ваше решение - это лаконичное продолжение и развитие моей мысли. Но к сожалению не решает мою изначальную проблему - проблему хардкода названия интерфейсов-аннотаций (то бишь свитч по строке).